# Как заставить клиента ждать ответа от сервера socket.io, node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Нужно сделать так чтобы клиент ждал ответа от сервера. Внутри блока socket.on(...) quest_data выдает желанный массив, за пределами блока выдает undefined.

Код клиента

```
var socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
var quest_data = [];
var answ_data = [];

function getAnswers(){
  //Поиск вопросов
    var quest = document.getElementsByClassName("qtext");
  //Запаковка их в объект
    var data = {
        questions: []
    }
    for(var i = 0;i<quest.length;i++) {
        data.questions[i] = quest[i].innerHTML;
    }
    console.log(data);
    //Отправка на сервер
    socket.emit("gimmeQA",data);
    console.log("Вопросы отправлены");
    console.log("Ждем ответа");
    //Получение ответов с сервера
    socket.on("gimmeQA",function(data){
        var my_json = JSON.parse(data);
        quest_data = my_json.questions;
        answ_data = my_json.answers;
        console.log("Данные получены");
        console.log(quest_data); //Получен массив вопросов
    });
}

getAnswers();
console.log(quest_data); //undefined
```

Код сервера node.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var fs = require("fs");

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on("disconnect",function(){
    console.log("user disconnected");
  });
  socket.on('gimmeQA', function(json_obj) {
    console.log('Запрос правильных ответов');
    socket.emit("gimmeQA", findAnswers(json_obj));
    console.log("Ответ отправлен");
  });
```

Comment: socket.on gimmeQA асинхронен, код внутри сработает как только сервер ответит на запрос, по этому его мажна вытащить из функции getAnswers(). По скольку quest_data придёт с задержкой, а исполнение кода клиент продолжиться ответ сервера нам будет неизвестен. поэтому обработать данные нужно в теле `socket.on("gimmeQA", function(data){ /* Code */});`

Comment: А можно как то остановить скрипт на стороне клиента? Чтобы socket.on стал синхронным.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему через Promises

Вот решение:

```
var socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
var quest_data = [];
var answ_data = [];

let getAnswers = function(){
  //Поиск вопросов
    var quest = document.getElementsByClassName("qtext");
  //Запаковка их в объект
    var data = {
        questions: []
    }
    for(var i = 0;i<quest.length;i++) {
        data.questions[i] = quest[i].innerHTML;
    }
    console.log(data);
    //Отправка на сервер
    socket.emit("gimmeQA",data);
    console.log("Вопросы отправлены");
    console.log("Ждем ответа");
    //Получение ответов с сервера
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    socket.on("gimmeQA",function(data){
      var my_json = JSON.parse(data);
      quest_data = my_json.questions;
      answ_data = my_json.answers;
      console.log("Данные получены");
      resolve("resolve")
    });
  });
}

getAnswers().then((msg) => {
    console.log("ура " + msg);
    console.log(quest_data);
  });
```

Исправил код теперь работает как надо.

Comment: Он  не должен выполниться, т.к. вы никогда не вызываете resolve

Comment: Попробовал не получилось let foryou = function(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    resolve("Получилось");
  });
}

  getAnswers(subject).then((msg) => {
    console.log("ура " + msg);
    foryou();
  });

Comment: И зачем сразу минусовать? Я ответил на свой же вопрос, задачу выполнил, код работает. В чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы проблему не решили, а подпёрли костылем. Код всё еще содержит ошибку в функции getAnswers

Comment: Вызывайте его лишь после того как пользователь получит сокет (что бы это ни означало)

Comment: все переделал, спасибо )